# Add CountIf Formula into Cell in VBA Code Syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if someone can help me with this syntax?  I am trying to inject a `CountIf` formula into cells in my Summary Sheet (which is the Active Sheet in this part of the code) and I am trying to reference cells in other worksheets of the workbook. The reason I am doing this is because I'd like any changes to happen in the worksheets other than the Summary Sheet to be updated right away in the Summary Sheet.

What I have so far for this portion is:

```
If Z=13 Then 'Z denotes the Sheet, in this case Summary Sheet 
  looped = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
  For i=1 to looped 'going through the rows 
    Cells(i, 1) = "=Countifs(Sheets1!A"& i & "Sheets1!A",Sheets2!A," & """ & ""UNTESTED"" & "")""
  Next 
End If
```

What I am having problems with is the syntax for the

```
Cells(i, 1) = "=Countifs(Sheets1!A" & i & "Sheets1!A",Sheets2!A," & """ & ""UNTESTED"" & "")""
```

What I want for this line to do is to go into each worksheet before the 13th worksheet and for each row, i , for that worksheet, to look into column A and to see if "UNTESTED" is in that cell. If it is, count, and so on.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be countifs? otherwise, why not just create the countifs using excel as a guidance, and then fill that in separately? As in, get a working countif in excel, then put it in the VBA code. The syntax for countifs you're using above wouldn't be correct. It also looks like you'd be overwriting each cell with a countif statement, which I don't think is what you want either.

Alternatively, I have two examples here in different subs below to summarize per sheet and for the workbook in VBA. I think that one of these is what you're looking for. You can print the value into the cell you want instead of to immediate window.

If you notice in the code i use `.Rows.Count` before xlUp to get the last row. This should keep that codes compatibility with other versions of Excel. Not all versions have the 1048576, although the majority do.

```
Option Explicit
Sub count_of_untested_total()
'Summarizes data for the workbook before summary sheet and prints to immediate window
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim i As Long

Const SUMMARY_SHEET = 13 'Index of the summary sheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wks
        'For all sheets before the summary sheet
        '(if they were created in order the index should be in
        'order, otherwise you should use names)
        If .Index < SUMMARY_SHEET Then
            'Get last row of current sheet for column A
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Loop through all rows for column A in current sheet
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                'increment cnt when column has untested
                'good to enforce common capitalization for comparisons
                If UCase(.Cells(i, 1)) = "UNTESTED" Then cnt = cnt + 1
            Next i
        End If
    End With
Next wks

Debug.Print "Number of Untested: " & cnt

End Sub

Sub count_of_untested_per_sheet()
'Summarizes data per sheet before summary sheet and prints to immediate window
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim i As Long

Const SUMMARY_SHEET = 13 'Index of the summary sheet

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wks
        'reset to 0 for each sheet
        cnt = 0
        'For all sheets before the summary sheet
        '(if they were created in order the index should be in
        'order, otherwise you should use names)
        If .Index < SUMMARY_SHEET Then
            'Get last row of current sheet for column A
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'Loop through all rows for column A in current sheet
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                'increment cnt when column has untested
                'good to enforce common capitalization for comparisons
                If UCase(.Cells(i, 1)) = "UNTESTED" Then cnt = cnt + 1
            Next i
        End If
        'Summary on each sheet
        Debug.Print "Number of Untested for " & .Name & ": " & cnt
    End With
Next wks

End Sub
```